# Are there any tutorials out there on how to implement "page-flip" into an android app?

Tags: android, image, view, flip

More specifically I am looking for one to try and flip views instead of images. I want the user to flip the page over like an e-book, to reveal more content underneath. I have 3 or 4 tutorials but they are all for images and I can't see any way to convert them to flip views.

Does anyone know of anything like this? Also, I will be implementing this into a 3.0/3.1 app, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example:
[Example](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-viewflipper-example)

Or you can also lookup for some Android Game Engines (And Engine) to get more flashy animations

Comment: I have gone through Curl effect as well as flip effect in android where pages of a book are turned but what i need is turn effect on book means when we have a book with first and last cover as hard bound then the turning style will be different from curl and flip effect. So please can any one tell me how to implement this and any supporting links or tutorials or examples (are appreciated ) Thank you